# Window id in xul

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I have a question regarding window id in xul. I have something like  in my xul file and I want to access this window from javascript. Basically, I want a function to return me a reference to that window using the name of it. Is there any function to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a top-level XUL window, you can get a reference to it using [nsIWindowMediator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWindowMediator), like this:

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
```

`navigator:browser` is the type of the browser window, you would have to use the [`windowtype` attribute value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/windowtype) of your window. Note that this isn't using the `id` attribute - the ID is a different thing and mostly useful to apply overlays.

To get more than one window of the same type you would write:

```js
var enumerator = Services.wm.getEnumerator("navigator:browser");
while (enumerator.hasMoreElements())
  alert(enumerator.getNext().QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow));
```